# {Magento} Advanced Options created how to set for each product in code

Tags: magento

We have an advanced product option created called Courses. It contains all the fields that we want the user to enter information when ordering the product.

We have an external process that imports our courses into our store using this shortened code: 
($data contains the course information to be inserted.)

```
$sku = $data['EventCode'];
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if(!$productId) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $product->setData('entity_type_id', '10');
    $product->setData('attribute_set_id', 4);
    $product->setData('type_id', 'virtual');
    $product->setData('created_at', strtotime('now'));
    $product->setData('updated_at', strtotime('now'));
    $product->setTaxClassId(1);
    $product->setStatus(1);
    $product->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    $product->setData('visibility', 1);
    $product->setData('has_options', 0);  // If this product has options, set to 1
    $product->setStockData(array('is_in_stock' => 1));
} else {
    // Product was found, so load it so it can be updated.
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
} // if(!$productId)
$ename = "Unknown course name";
$product->setName($ename);
$product->setPrice($data['Price']);
$product->setDescription('Course Item');
$product->setShortDescription('Course Item');
$product->setData('is_online_course', ($data['LocState'] == 'OL' ? 1 : 0));
$product->setSku($sku);
$cat_id[] = 9;
$product->setData('category_ids', $cat_id);
$product->save();
```

How would I set each product to use the advanced option Courses in the code above?
Note: All options in Courses are required.

Comment: just to be clarification. You had created "Attribute" set that named "Course", right? Then, you have been inserted new attributes under "Course" attribute set, right?

Comment: Catalog->Advanced Product Options->Add Options. That is where we added the Course option group. We added 12 options to it. The Magento terminology is a little different than I'm used to.

Comment: I think you are using Enterprise Edition which isn't available that you mentioned menu in community edition or you used an extension.

Comment: Community Magento ver. 1.4.0.1

Comment: I guess it could be MageWorx Extensions-Advanced Product Options v1.0.2

Comment: I will submit a support ticket to MageWorx to see if they can offer any insight on how to do this then I'll post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use product Attributes API.

```
<?php
   $proxy = new SoapClient('http://domain/api/soap/?wsdl');
   $sesId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
   $attributeSet = $proxy->call($sessId, 'product_attribute_set.list');
   $attributeOptions = $proxy->call($sessId, 'product_attribute.options', array('attribute_id'=>'PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_INT_ID'));
   // change PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_INT_ID with your attribute id

?>
```

Comment: I don't think it is the same thing because these options are stored in tables called catalog_product_option, catalog_product_option_price, catalog_product_option_title catalog_product_option_type_price, catalog_product_option_type_title, and catalog_product_option_type_value

Comment: I posted a ticket on MageWorx's support system to see if they can help. I will post their replies.

Comment: Here's what they posted: Please try to add the following code after save option:

    $productId = $product->getId();
    $groupData = Mage::getSingleton('customoptions/group')->load($groupId);
    $optionsHash = unserialize($groupData->getData('hash_options'));                        
    Mage::getModel(' customoptions/product_option')->saveProductOptions($optionsHash, array(), array($productId), $groupData, 1, false, 'product');

where $groupId - id of templates group; $productId - id of a product; $optionsHash - array with options that should be applied to a product.